# text box printing it's own html code inside the text box

Tags: javascript, html

I have table and I am creating rows and cells in it dynamically and by  clicking on any cell it creates input text box inside that cell and put the cell value in the text box, the problem is when I click again on the same text box it prints the html of that text box inside the text box.

```
var allTds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");      
var tdsLength = allTds.length;

for(var i=0; i<tdsLength;i++){          
  allTds[i].onclick = function (){ 
      var valOfThisTd = this.innerHTML;
    var tds = this.parentNode.childNodes;           
      for(var j=1; j<tds.length-1;j++){                  
        tds[j].ondblclick = function(){                                                          
          this.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='"+valOfThisTd+"' style='width:100px;'>";
                console.log(this.innerHTML);
           }                  
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, you should be bale to solve this by simply adding a check on click. If this cell has an input already, don't add another one. Does that sound like what you need?

Comment: check like (if valOfThisTd != ""){this.innerHTML = <input ....>} is this what you mean

Comment: yeah, depending on the markup you insert, i would do a `querySelector` for a container or something. Something that you are sure will either be there or not. Then your test will be pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Cause the second time your td's innerHtml is "`<input type='text' value='someValue' style='width:100px;'>`", you need to get the td value from another source

Comment: how can i do that? I am new to these things

Comment: Well... all we know is that you have a table, you can use an attribute on the td, some like this: <td data-value="your value"/>. But your table, is a dinamyc table?